# "Mock" method with fixed parameters

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a "Mailer" class in my project (which of course sends emails). For testing I want that every call of `Mailer#send(String toAddress)` is replaced with `Mailer#send("mail@example.com")`.

So something like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassCallingMailer.class})
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Mailer mailerMock = mock(Mailer.class);
        // this is where the magic happens; replace any toAddress with fixed email address
        when(mailerMock.send(any(String.class))).thenReturn(mailerMock.send("mail@example.com"));
        try {
            whenNew(Mailer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mailerMock);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ClassCallingMailer someClass = new ClassCallingMailer();
        assertTrue(someClass.methodSendingMail());
    }
}
```

This code obviously is not working, but can this be achieved in some way?
Maybe this is a completely wrong approach?

Thank you.

---

### UPDATE

I'm not really sure how good this is but it's working:

```
// ClassCallingMailer (no changes, just for completeness)
public class ClassCallingMailer {
    public boolean methodSendingMail() {
        Mailer mail = new Mailer();
        return mail.send(someEmailAddress);
    }
}

// TestMailer (new class)
public class TestMailer extends Mailer {
    // add all constructors from Mailer
    @Override
    public boolean send(String to) {
        return super.send("mail@example.com");
    }
}

// TestClass (with changes)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassCallingMailer.class})
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        // changed mock to spy and replaced Mailer with TestMailer
        Mailer mailerMock = spy(TestMailer.class);
        // removed "when(...).thenReturn(...)"
        try {
            whenNew(Mailer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mailerMock);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ClassCallingMailer someClass = new ClassCallingMailer();
        assertTrue(someClass.methodSendingMail());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve only this behavior, I would suggest not to do by mocking.
You can extend your `Mailer` class to have some `TestMailer` in which you can do something like:

```
@Override
public void send(String toAddress){
  super.send("mail@example.com");
}
```

Basically you override the original send from the `Mailer` and call it with the predefined address.

You can use this new subclass in your tests.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you meant, but what I did (and it worked) was 1. create `TestMailer` (like you suggested) 2. replace `Mailer mailerMock = mock(Mailer.class);` with `Mailer mailerMock = spy(TestMailer.class);` 3. remove `when(mailerMock.send(...`

Comment: No I didn't mean that, but I'm glad that you found out that you have to use `spy` instead of `mock`, because you want to use the `send` method. Calling a method of a mocked class would not do anything. With spy you basically end up with a similar object as it would have been created by `new`, do the when-then trick :D

Comment: Well since the `Mailer` instance is not passed as a parameter but is created inline, I was't sure how to replace it with an instance of `TestMailer`. But thanks a lot (:

Comment: I added my solution to the question. Any feedback?